# Improper usage of await-async causes a lost connection

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, async-await, python-asyncio

I'm experiencing an issue with using async functions in relation to an API. When I use multiple levels of await-async.
This error occurs on message that I send to the generate() function of GPT 3.5, which sends a request.
But when I call it differently without going through these different levels of await async, it works without any issues and it doesn't lose the connection. I don't understand why.

I encounter the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1152, in _create_direct_connection
    hosts = await asyncio.shield(host_resolved)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 874, in _resolve_host
    addrs = await self._resolver.resolve(host, port, family=self._family)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/resolver.py", line 33, in resolve
    infos = await self._loop.getaddrinfo(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 867, in getaddrinfo
    return await self.run_in_executor(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/socket.py", line 962, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 656, in connect
    self.ws = await asyncio.wait_for(coro, timeout=60.0)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/tasks.py", line 479, in wait_for
    return fut.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/gateway.py", line 372, in from_client
    socket = await client.http.ws_connect(str(url))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 536, in ws_connect
    return await self.__session.ws_connect(url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 779, in _ws_connect
    resp = await self.request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 536, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 540, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 901, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1166, in _create_direct_connection
    raise ClientConnectorError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host gateway-us-east1-c.discord.gg:443 ssl:default [nodename nor servname provided, or not known]
2023-06-11 07:28:12 INFO     discord.gateway Shard ID None session has been invalidated.
2023-06-11 08:06:28 ERROR    discord.client Attempting a reconnect in 321.36s
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1152, in _create_direct_connection
    hosts = await asyncio.shield(host_resolved)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 874, in _resolve_host
    addrs = await self._resolver.resolve(host, port, family=self._family)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/resolver.py", line 33, in resolve
    infos = await self._loop.getaddrinfo(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 867, in getaddrinfo
    return await self.run_in_executor(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/socket.py", line 962, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 656, in connect
    self.ws = await asyncio.wait_for(coro, timeout=60.0)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/tasks.py", line 479, in wait_for
    return fut.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/gateway.py", line 372, in from_client
    socket = await client.http.ws_connect(str(url))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 536, in ws_connect
    return await self.__session.ws_connect(url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 779, in _ws_connect
    resp = await self.request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 536, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 540, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 901, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1166, in _create_direct_connection
    raise ClientConnectorError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host gateway-us-east1-c.discord.gg:443 ssl:default [nodename nor servname provided, or not known]
```

It seems like the connection is being lost.

However, if I call the same function (await mygpt().generate(message.content)) directly without passing by parse.run(), this issue doesn't occur. I'm almost certain that the problem lies in how I'm using my await-async functions.

My code:

The problem start here

```
await parse().run(message, message.channel.send)
```

from bot.py and when it calls

```
await mygpt().generate(message.content)
```

the gpt api

bot.py

```
import os
import discord
from gpt import MyGPT
from mode_gpt import ModeGPT as mode
from parse_commands import ParseCommands as parse

class MyBot(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self):
        mode.set("text-generator")
        super().__init__(intents=self.get_intents())

    def get_intents(self):
        intents = discord.Intents.default()
        intents.message_content = True
        return intents

    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'We have logged in as {self.user}')

    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == self.user:
            return
        if message.content == '!gpt':
            user = message.author
            dm_channel = await user.create_dm()
            await dm_channel.send("Welcome to the KoKo bot, {}!\nPlease enter your prompt.".format(user.name))
        if isinstance(message.channel, discord.DMChannel):
            await parse().run(message, message.channel.send)

    def run(self):
        bot_token = os.environ.get("DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN")
        if bot_token is not None:
            super().run(bot_token)
        else:
            print("Discord bot token is not set in the environment variables.")
```

parse_commands.py

```
from parse_mode import ParseMode as pm
from mode_gpt import ModeGPT as mgpt
from gpt import MyGPT as mygpt
import discord

class ParseCommands():
    def __init__(self):
        self.pm = pm()

    async def mode(self, message, send):
        return await self.pm(message, send)

    async def commands(self, message, send):
        match mgpt.get():
            case "text-generator":
                response = await mygpt().generate(message.content)
                await send(response)
                return True
            case "image-generator":
                response = await mygpt().generate_image(message.content)
                await send(response)
                return True
            case _:
                return False
    async def run(self, message, send):
        if not await self.mode(message, send):
           await self.commands(message, send)
```

gpt.py

```
import openai_async

_OPEN_AI_API_KEY = ""

class MyGPT:
    async def generate(self, prompt):
        response = await openai_async.chat_complete(
            _OPEN_AI_API_KEY,
            timeout=15,
            payload={
                "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
                "messages": [{"role": "user", "content": prompt}],
            },
        )
        return response.json()["choices"][0]["message"]["content"]

    async def generate_image(self, prompt):
        response = await openai_async.generate_img(
            _OPEN_AI_API_KEY,
            timeout=8,
            payload={
                "prompt": prompt,
                "n": 1,
                "size": "512x512"
            },
        )
        return response.json()["data"][0]["url"]
```